# Python/Javascript Dash DataTable Clientside Callbacks

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I cannot figure out how to transform a dash_table.DataTable server-side call back in a client-side callback in Plotly Dash using javascript.

Below an example:

```
def function1(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    .....
    return df

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dcc.Interval('live-update', interval=50000, n_intervals=0),
    dcc.Store(id='stored_data'),
    dcc.Store(id='stored_data1'),
    html.Div(id='t1')])

@app.callback(
    Output('stored_data', 'data'),
    Input('live-update', 'n_intervals'))
def stored_data(n):
    return pd.read_csv('Test.csv').to_dict('records')

@app.callback(
    Output('stored_data1', 'data'),
    Input('stored_data', 'data'))
def table_1(data):
    df = function1(data)
    df = dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'id': i, 'name': i,
                 'type': 'numeric'} for i in df.columns])
    return df

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(data) {
        return {
           data[type=table]
             }
        }
    """,
    Output('t1', 'children'),
    Input('stored_data1', 'data'),
)
```

With a server-side callback I would Output directly the `t1` within the second callback however I don't understand how to use the clientside_callback, all examples I found are using a chart not a table.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS code. You won't be able to use the pandas library in a clientside callback. Is there a reason you don't want to do it server side?

Comment: I would like to use a client callback to speed up the generation of tables since I have many tables to update from a database that updates every 30 minutes with the dcc.Interval. Do you know a way to do so?

Comment: How slow is it when you use normal callbacks?

Comment: very slow it takes more than a minute to load a page. there are more than 30 functions to load all of then quite similar. It is a muti-page app

Comment: The clientside callback is an option, but it's possible that it might not be enough. Could you lazy load the app so the other pages aren't taking up resources loading before they've been viewed? You could also look for ways to `PreventUpdate` in some of the functions until the user needs them, like after clicking a button.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about Flask-Caching, do you think could be a good solution?

Comment: That probably wouldn't help your initial load time, only subsequent loads after the cache is populated.